# External makefile to call Eclipse CDT's generated makefile - according to Debug\ Release config

Tags: c++, debugging, makefile, release, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse CDT on Linux to build a c++ executable and several static libraries which the executable depends on.
Everything is good - Eclipse generates the makefiles for both Debug and Release as expected.

However, I want to compile this code also on a computer without Eclipse installed, so I thought to write a simple makefile which calls the Eclipse makefile.

So I started with something like:

```
all:  
cd Lib1/Release && make all  
cd Lib2/Release && make all  
...  
cd Exec/Release && make all
```

This works for Release only, as you see...

How can I change the makefile so I can use the selected user's configuration ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not write two scripts, say `build-dbg` and `build-rel`? Or one script that gets an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this in your makefile you can invoke 'make debug' or 'make release' to build all the projects in the required mode :

```
config:
    cd Lib1/$(CONFIG) && make all
    ...
    cd LibN/$(CONFIG) && make all
    cd Exec/$(CONFIG) && make all
debug:
    make config CONFIG=Debug 
release:
    make config CONFIG=Release
.PHONY: debug release config
```