# Eclipse CDT Headless Build Question

Tags: eclipse-cdt

Using Eclipse CDT 7.0, is there a way to specifiy to build just a single build configuration on the commandline when doing a headless build?

Comment: Hi! check out this post :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780202/external-makefile-to-call-eclipse-cdts-generated-makefile-according-to-debug

Comment: I was just looking for a way to use the headless build feature of CDT-7.0 to perform the build, mostly as a way to optimize the CM teams process, as if I can do that I can simplify their process for the build of one of our products down to 2 steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my own question, mostly by playing with CDT 8.0 and the indigo developer releases and looking at cdt 7.0: answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078857/headless-build-with-cdt-using-cproject-configuration/5442765#5442765)

short summary is:

- 7.0: doesn't seem to support building a specific configuration
- 7.0.1: I don't know. don't have any way to try this
- 7.0.2: this version supports it although there doesn't seem to be any documentation on exactly how.